# Save Permissions Python

Tags: python-2.7, io, pyinstaller, advanced-installer

I am writing a program which tracks pay stub information. It runs fine when running it from source code via the terminal and saves files correctly. In order to distribute it to my client, I compiled the code using PyInstaller to create a 1 file .exe for distribution on Windows 7, and then used Advanced Installer 11.4.1 to create a .msi file for them to install on their platform.

My problem is when running the application after installing the .msi. In the package I distributed a .txt file with the data to load and save to.

When attempting to update the file I distributed the following error occurs:

> IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'testSave.txt'

The code I'm using to try and save the file is:

```
saving = open(file_name, 'w')
saving.write(data)
```

Is there a way to tell Python 2.7 to write regardless of privileges, or to make this specific file have basic user privileges when installing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Advanced Installer you can [set permissions](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/permissions.html), but you need a licensed edition, i.e. Professional or higher.

You can also build a Professional project in the trial period, to test the permissions support and see if it will work for you.

Comment: Thank you, I can't find the link right now to the post about writing to programs file, but I was able to modify my code to read/write to the users app folder using the system environment variables, and installing my .txt to that location using Advanced Installer. I don't plan on making programs advanced enough to warrant buying the Professional license right now.

Answer (score 1):

I modified my program to write to a different location using the system environment and telling Advanced Installer to install the .txt in the Local App Data directory. This allowed me to open the file with 'rw' privileges.

```
path = os.environ.get('LOCALAPPDATA')
path = path.split('\\')
real_path = ''
print path
for dir in path:
    real_path += dir + '/'
print real_path
real_path = os.path.normpath(real_path + 'PayTrakker/testSave.txt')
```